# Поддерживает ли mysql символ обратный слэш?

Tags: php, mysql

Добавляю запись в MySql, но из строки пропадают все обратные слэши `\`. В чем дело?

Answer (score 4):

Как и в большинстве языков программирования `\` используется для экранирования символов (что бы например можно было поместить кавычки в строку с кавычками). Что бы поместить в строку обратный слеш его необходимо написать дважды.

Подробнее в [Документации](http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/String_syntax.html)

Пример на [sqlfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e44382/1)